# Maintaining Transaction for a Channel configured with Message Store - Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am new to Spring integration and am basically just trying to learn. I am trying to test channel message store with mysql db. Here is my spring config

```
<beans:bean id="jdbcChannelStore" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="channelMessageStoreQueryProvider">
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.channel.MySqlChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

 <beans:bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TESTDB" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="######" />
</beans:bean> 


<!-- instanceRequests are processed by the filter one -->
<int:channel id="instanceRequests">
    <int:queue capacity="20" message-store="jdbcChannelStore"/>
    <int:interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="com.trivialjava.rnd.interceptors.TimingInterceptor">
            <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:array>
                    <beans:value>com.trivialjava.rnd.entity.InstanceRequest</beans:value>
                    <beans:value>com.trivialjava.rnd.entity.SolutionRequest</beans:value>

                </beans:array>
            </beans:constructor-arg>
        </beans:bean>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:service-activator input-channel="instanceRequests" ref="instanceRequestNameHandler" method="prepareName" output-channel="instanceRequestsDesc"/>
```

As you will see that the channel instanceRequests has been configured with  message store in Mariadb. I have noticed that the table **INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE**  is populated when the message comes in and as soon as the handler **instanceRequestNameHandler** reads the message, it deletes the record.

My requirement is that if for some reason there is a system failure when the handler is processing, the message should stay in the INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE table until another node picks it up or the system restarts.When i say system failure, i mean the server stops or restarts, not business errors, for business erros i can add error channels. Therefore there should be some sort of rollback on system failure, but that is not happening now.

Can I do something about this or SI doesnot support this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable transactions on the poller. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html). The transaction will be committed when the downstream flow completes.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell !! I followed the steps for transaction and it is working now. I will add an answer as to how i have done that

Answer (score 0):

Well Spring Integration does support transaction for a channel which has a message store. This is how i implemented a very basic transaction to make sure that even in the case os system failures the message stays in the store

```
<!-- added a simple transaction for the poller-->
<int:poller id="poller" default="true" fixed-delay="30000">
    <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</int:poller>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>
```

I tested this in a simulated clustered scenario, so if one node reads a record from the channel it takes a lock on the record and other processed from another node is not able to read and process the record. If the first instance is restarted/stopped it releases the lock and the node process does pick it up